# Actionscript 3 how to gotoAndPlay without pressing buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So, I have movieclip named intro. When the intro runs out of frames, how do I tell it to gotoandPlay to maintimeline or upper movieclip without needing user to press any buttons? shouldnt be that hard, right? it was really super easy in actionscript 2, but in 3 I cant even seem to find help/tutorial to do this!

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clarify what exactly you would like to play afterwards?

It could be as simple as adding a line of code to the last frame of the animation:

```
gotoAndPlay(3); // will goto a frame within the same move clip
```

Or to play a different movieclip:

```
MovieClip(this.parent as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(3); //tell your parent to goto a specific frame
```

Or

```
MovieClip(this.parent as MovieClip).parentObject.gotoAndPlay(3); //tell one of your parents movieclips to start playing
```

EDIT:

A bit more out there method, placing this code on the parents timeline to check when the movieclip is finished:

```
intro.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);

function checkFrame(e:Event):void{
    if(intro.currentFrame==intro.totalFrames){
        //do something
        someMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to play next frame on maintimeline after the movieclip runs out of frames, so the intro movieclip doesnt just loop over and over again

Comment: Good answer @Kayo, but with `MovieClip(this.parent as MovieClip)` - you seem to be casting `this.parent` twice. Either `MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay()` or `(this.parent as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay()` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: True JcFx, It's just a habit I got into while forcing something to cast to something else, but unnecessary.

Comment: thanks a lot Kayo :) before you edited, your second option just worked fine once I placed it to correct (correct being last) frame. But I think I´ll end up using the method you added :) thanks again!

Comment: the last method is definitely easier to maintain, no moving code around if you decide to change your animations :)